# Request for new tag: euthanasia

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Could someone create a tag for me?

I wold like the tag euthanasia for my question on the board

TIA

Answer (score 2):

The tag [euthanasia](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euthanasia) is already in place and has several questions attached to it.